# How to add a .TTF file into Java ME application

Tags: java-me, fonts, midp, midlet

I'm developing j2me application and want to add a custom font into that.So how to add a .ttf file  into a j2me project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can't use .ttf file for Java ME application. If you want to use custom font, [look on this discussion.](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?122363-Custom-font)

I suggest you can use LWUIT framework. Here you can use different type of bitmap fonts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.i am using LWUIT framework in my j2me application.

Comment: @ Megha, So you can create the new font in ResourceEdit and use it.

Comment: Thanks i create the font using LWUIT framework and it allowed me to add different font.but i want to add Open Sans Semibold into my application which is not in the list of font creation  in the LWUIT framework .

Comment: @ Megha, you can't add a new font in ResourceEdit. So try to use [custom fonts.](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_create_custom_fonts_in_Java_ME)

Comment: @Megha, try installing this font in the system and then read it into the ResourceEditor.

Comment: @Bharath, it does work on device. Megha, try my [Localization app](www.megaupload.com/?d=7QSSW6UV) netbeans project. I have tested this app on some devices Nokia S^3, S60 3rd Ed FP1. The password to the zip is `lwuitl10n`. And yes if things don't pan out the way you want bharath's solution will surely work.